# Followup: Use backtracking to put as many ships on a battleship-board as possible

Tags: java, backtracking, battleship

I created a simple battleship game and wanted to be able to place as many ships on my board as possible.
The logic to place the ships uses some kind of backtracking to find a correct placement.

Correct placement

```
|1|1|O|
|2|2|4|
|3|3|4|
```

Wrong placement

```
|0|1|1|
|2|2|0|
|0|3|3|
```

First I wrote a recursive backtracking solution for the ship placement but it was too slow and had too many recursive calls leading to stackoverflows for harder problems.
﻿﻿
I am particularly interested in feedback for the following parts:

- Ship cells (better use a cell class?)
- placeShips method

[Github](https://github.com/apoc-dev/BattleShip)

**Ship Class**:

```java
package src;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Ship {

    String color;
    ArrayList<String> cells = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> cells_hit = new ArrayList<>();

    Ship(String col) {
        color = col;
    }

    public void setCells(ArrayList<String> cells) {
        this.cells = cells;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getCells() {
        return this.cells;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getCells_hit() {
        return this.cells_hit;
    }

    public String checkYourself(String stringTip) {

        String result = "Miss";

        if (this.cells.contains(stringTip)) {
            result = "Hit";
            this.cells_hit.add(stringTip);
            this.cells.remove(stringTip);
        }

        if (this.cells.isEmpty()) {
            result = "submerged";
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

**BattleShip Class**:

````java
package src;

import java.util.*;

public class BattleShip {

    final int shipLength = 3;
    final int fieldSize = 5;
    final int numberOfShipsToPlace = 8;

    final boolean DEBUG = true;
    final boolean DEBUG_BACKTRACKING = false;
    final boolean START_GAME = false;

    final ArrayList<Ship> ships = new ArrayList<>();

    TerminalColours color = new TerminalColours();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        BattleShip game = new BattleShip();
        game.prepareGame();

        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start + " milliseconds to prepare");

        if (game.START_GAME)
            game.startGame();

        if (!game.START_GAME)
            game.printGame();

    }

    public void printGame() {

        for (int row = 0; row < fieldSize; row++) {
            System.out.println();

            for (int column = 0; column < fieldSize; column++) {
                boolean columnPrinted = false;
                System.out.print("|");
                for (Ship ship : ships) {
                    ArrayList<String> cells;

                    if (DEBUG) {
                        cells = ship.getCells();
                    } else {
                        cells = ship.getCells_hit();
                    }

                    for (String cell : cells) {

                        if (cell.equals((toAlphabetic(row)) + Integer.toString(column))) {

                            System.out.print(ship.getColor() + "X");
                            System.out.print(TerminalColours.ANSI_RESET);
                            columnPrinted = true;
                        }
                    }

                }
                if (!columnPrinted) {
                    System.out.print("O");
                }
            }

            System.out.print("|");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
    }

    public void prepareGame() {

        if (!(fieldSize * fieldSize / shipLength >= numberOfShipsToPlace)) {
            System.out.println("Error: Game numbers are invalid");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfShipsToPlace; i++) {
            ships.add(new Ship(color.randomTerminalColor()));
        }

        if (!placeShips(numberOfShipsToPlace)) {
            System.out.println("Ship placement failed. Terminating.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

    }

    private boolean placeShips(int shipsToPlace) {

        int maxTries = 100;
        int maxBacktrackTries = 10;
        int currentBacktrackTrie = 0;
        int backtrackStep = 1;
        int currentTry = 0;
        int currentShipIndex = 0;
        ArrayList<String> randomCells;

        while (currentShipIndex < shipsToPlace) {

            randomCells = generateCells();

            if (!isCollision(randomCells)) {
                ships.get(currentShipIndex).setCells(randomCells);
                currentShipIndex++;
                currentTry = 0;
            } else {
                currentTry++;
            }

            if (currentTry >= maxTries) {
                if (currentBacktrackTrie > maxBacktrackTries) {
                    backtrackStep++;
                    currentBacktrackTrie = 0;
                    currentShipIndex = currentShipIndex - backtrackStep;
                } else {
                    currentShipIndex--;
                    currentBacktrackTrie++;
                }
                if (currentShipIndex < 0) {
                    currentShipIndex = 0; // this may be wrong behaviour if there is no solution for ship placement
                }
                resetShips(currentShipIndex); // to set all cells of ships above this back to null
                currentTry = 0;
            }

        }

        return true;

    }

    private void resetShips(int newEnd) {
        for (int shipIndex = newEnd; shipIndex < numberOfShipsToPlace; shipIndex++) {
            ships.get(shipIndex).setCells(new ArrayList<String>());
        }
    }

    public boolean isCollision(ArrayList<String> cells) {

        for (Ship ship : ships) {

            if (!Collections.disjoint(cells, ship.getCells())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> generateCells() {
        ArrayList<String> cells = new ArrayList<>();

        int alignment = (int) (Math.random() * 2);

        if (alignment == 0) { // x graph
            int x = (int) (Math.random() * (fieldSize - shipLength + 1));
            int y = (int) (Math.random() * fieldSize);

            // build ship with specified length in "ship_length"
            for (int i = 0; i < shipLength; i++) {
                cells.add(toAlphabetic(y) + (x + i));
            }

        }
        if (alignment == 1) { // y graph
            int x = (int) (Math.random() * fieldSize);
            int y = (int) (Math.random() * (fieldSize - shipLength + 1));

            // build ship with specified length in "ship_length"
            for (int i = 0; i < shipLength; i++) {
                cells.add(toAlphabetic(y + i) + (x));
            }

        }
        return cells;
    }

    public void startGame() {
        int totalTips = 0;
        boolean alive = true;
        while (alive) {
            printGame();
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); // Create a Scanner object
            System.out.println("Tip?");

            String tip = scanner.nextLine().toUpperCase();
            Iterator<Ship> itr = ships.iterator();

            while (itr.hasNext()) {

                Ship ship = itr.next();

                String result = ship.checkYourself(tip);
                System.out.println(result);

                if (result.equals("submerged")) {
                    itr.remove();
                }
            }

            totalTips++;
            if (ships.isEmpty()) {
                alive = false;
                System.out.println(totalTips + " tips needed");
            }

            scanner.close();

        }

    }

    // not my code
    public static String toAlphabetic(int i) {

        // negative numbers
        if (i < 0) {
            return "-" + toAlphabetic(-i - 1);
        }

        // toAlphabetic function
        int quot = i / 26;
        int rem = i % 26;
        char letter = (char) ((int) 'A' + rem);

        if (quot == 0) {
            return "" + letter;
        } else {
            return toAlphabetic(quot - 1) + letter;
        }
    }
}
```
````

Comment: For your particular problem: Start in the top left corner. From top to bottom, fill each row with as many ships as will fit horizontally. Find the top of the first column that doesn't have ships in it. From left to right, fill each column with as many ships as will fit vertically. The more general solution is trying to solve the 2D Knapsack problem, which is NP Hard if I'm recalling correctly.

Comment: Fora a generic solution with fixed size ships, you can quit as soon as the number of free cells on the board is less than the ship size. Your solution has a fixed ship count (8) which I think conflicts with the problem statement.

Comment: Did not really know there is a problem like that. Just coded a battleship game and wanted to place as many ships as possible if wanted by user.
Using a generic solution or something similar would kind of destroy the game itself imo. I want to be able to place the maximum number or less and have a random board each time.